# mysql equi of wm_concat

Tags: mysql

What is the mysql equi of wm_concat?

Answer (score 5):

`GROUP_CONCAT()` is the MySQL equivalent of `WM_CONCAT()` in Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

```
concat_ws
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws